# How To Search OLE/COM?

Tags: windows, com, ole

I want to look-up a registered COM type on my Windows system. I've tried using the OLE/COM object viewer but there's no search-method (very stupidly so).
So what is my alternative I wonder?

Comment: COM does not use names, programmers suck at picking unique names, it uses GUIDs.  A symbolic name is only available from a type library or a .h file generated from the IDL.  They disappear again when the compiler turned them back into GUIDs.  You focused too much on complaining about it to guess what you know about the type, the FIle > View Typelib command decompiles a type library.

Comment: @HansPassant so, how do I search via GUID then? Mr. smarty-pants.

Comment: @Olivier10178 you can look for the GUID in the windows registry, you'll find the associated COM dll/exe , I agree it is not very convenient but I don't know other way.